# ¿Cómo montar una imagen entre dos div diagonal encima de otros (se usó z-index)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

```css
.section{
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#section1{
  background:#f47070;
  z-index: 10/*10*/; 
}
#section2{
  background-image: url('img/Elementos/parallax-blue.jpg');
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
  z-index: 9;
  height: 400px !important;
  /*transform-origin: left bottom;
 transform: skewY(4deg);*/
}
#section3{
  background: #f5f567;
  z-index: 8;
}
#section4{
  background: #83ec89;
  z-index: 7;
}
#section5{
  background: #f47070;
  z-index: 6;
}
#section6{
  background: #f5d36e;
  z-index: 5;
}


.compu {z-index: 14 !important; height: 570px; width: 622px; margin-top: -4%; }


.section::after{
  content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 background: inherit;
 z-index: -1;
 bottom: 0;
}
#section1::after, #section2::after, #section4::after{
 transform-origin: left bottom;
 transform: skewY(4deg);
}

.ver::after, .ver::before {
 transform-origin: left bottom !important;
 transform: skewY(4deg) !important;
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 background: inherit;
 z-index: -1;
 bottom: 0;
}


#section2::after {height: 400px !important;}

#section2::after img::after {content: ''; margin-top:-10px; z-index: -14 !important; position: absolute;}
#section3::after, #section5::after{
 transform-origin: right bottom;
 transform: skewY(-3deg);
}
.sectionInner{
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 200px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
 <div class="sectionWrapper">
      <div id="section1" class="section">
          <div class="sectionInner">
            Section One
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="section2" class="section ver" style="border: 1px black solid;">
          <!--<div class="sectionInner">
            Section Two
          </div> -->
          <div class="contenedorCuroos">
     <img src="img/Elementos/computadora.png" class="compu" style="left: 0; position: relative; margin-left: -6%;">
     <div class="cajaCursos" style="position: absolute; margin-top: 0 !important;">
     <h2>Cursos básicos</h2>
     <p>Conoce los requisitos e inscríbete y participa en los cursos y talleres de la Biblioteca Virtual</p>
     <button class="boton" role="button" style="z-index: 3;">Consultar</button>
    </div>
    </div>
        
      </div>
      <div id="section3" class="section">
          <div class="sectionInner">
            Section Three
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="section4" class="section">
          <div class="sectionInner">
            Section Four
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="section5" class="section">
          <div class="sectionInner">
            Section Five
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="section6" class="section">
          <div class="sectionInner">
            Section Six
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Estoy diseñando un sitio que me encargaron, y debo de montar o superponer una imagen en un div diagonal,. He usado z-index, pero todavía no sale. También he usado clip-path para cortar parte del div, pero igual corta la imagen. Dicha imagen debe estar dentro del contenedor, pero que lo sobreponga; también debe ser responsiva y la imagen queda dentro del contenedor sin superponer (eso ya quedó).
Alguna idea para solucionar? En el enlace está el diseño como debe quedar. Es la imagen home-biblio-1 
En el código es una muestra de ejemplo, basta con que esté bien la img de la lap
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/f0l17khuwn60a08/AAAd36bdmw5oGN8MJm5lfPOna?dl=0

Comment: Podrás subir la imagen del home-biblio-1 a otro sitio? Tengo bloqueado dropbox.

Comment: Lo puse en Google Drive. Ahí puse otra img de cómo me quedó de muestra un ejemplo que todavía no sale https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KCZSJfVRdzuvfTFjUZp9IdZ2tpkJs4qs

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de lograrlo, yo por ejemplo te recomiendo esta estructura:

```
<section>
  <figure class="fondo"></figure>
  <figure class="foto">
    <img src="Laptop.png" alt="">
  </figure>
</section>
```

**Todos los hijos de cada section le pondría por defecto position:relative y un z-index: 2**; Es decir, manejaria 2 capas de nivel.

El fondo sería un **figure que estará distorsionado y sería un hijo del section**. Le agrego un **overflow** y un **z-index: 1;**.

Y **la imagen de fondo la pondría como seudo-elemento tipo ::before** del contenedor del fondo y restauraria la distorsión.

De resto, la imagen y textos, serían z-index: 2 o 3, según necesite. Te coloco un ejemplo:

```css
section:nth-child(2){
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 5em;
}

section:nth-child(2)>*:not(.fondo){
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.fondo{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%; /*lo centra verticalmente*/
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 125%;
  background-color: rgba(100,210,255,1);
  overflow: hidden;
          transform: 
    translateY(-50%) /*lo centra verticalmente*/
    skewY(-5deg);
}

.fondo::before,
.fondo::after{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25%;
  left: -25%;
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fondo::before, foto{
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/3200/1800/?random');
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(5deg);
          transform: skewY(5deg);  
}

.foto{  
  height: 150%;
  min-height: 20em;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-15%);
          transform: translateY(-15%);
}

.foto img{
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 90vh;
  display: inline-block;
}

/*================
CLASES DECORATIVAS
==================*/

*{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section{
  height: 50vh;
  min-height: 16em;
}

section:first-child{
  background: whitesmoke;
}

section:last-child{
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<section>
  <figure class="fondo"></figure>
  <figure class="foto">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/High-Performance-Desktop-Replacement-Slim-Laptop.png" alt="">
  </figure>
</section>
<section></section>
```

Comment: Gracias. YA revisé. Alguna idea sobre el efecto de parallax? Le coloqué los estilos, pero sale el contenedor azul que le puso y no debería pasar eso. Los estilos del parallax son estos:    background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-attachment: fixed;

Comment: De hecho, algo parecido hice antes, le puse literal solo skewY sin encimar un div tras otro como el código que puse arriba y me pasa que con el parallax, se ve que está atravesando el parte del otro contenedor que no sería diagonal. Aquí dejo el drive donde hay una captura de pantalla de cómo me quedó como puse del código de arriba, drive.google.com/open?id=1KCZSJfVRdzuvfTFjUZp9IdZ2tpkJs4qs

Comment: Sin ver el codigo que estas usando, me es un poco dificil suponer que esta pasando. En cuanto al parallax, ese que dices es un seudo parallax que se logra con css, si te refieres a que no funciona con mi codigo probablemente se deba a una o dos razones. 1. La imagen no es lo suficientemente alta y 2. Cambia Top a 0 y el translateY quitalo, solo deja el skew.